# How do I make a sharepoint formula that calculates date different based on when a value was last entered

Tags: sharepoint, date, formula

Here's the problem I'm trying to solve.  I have an Infopath form that users fill out and submit to a SharePoint library, and every field on the form is mapped to a SharePoint column.

Column A will have the name of a department, and column B will have the date that an occurrence was submitted on that department.  There are several departments to choose from.  I need to make a calculated column (column C) that will show how many days its been since an occurrence was reported on a specific unit.

Data will be set up like this:

```
A      B            C
1 South 4/20/2013   0
2 East  4/15/2013   8
3 South 4/18/2013   5
1 South 4/23/2013   0
```

C should calculate the amount of days since the last occurrence was reported for a specific unit.  Assuming the current date is 4/23/13, column C should so the following values for each unit.  1 South would be 0 since there was an occurrence reported on the current day.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a calculated column and use [Today] and subtract it from the value of column B. So you can implement like below:

```
=DATEDIF([B], [Today],"d")
```

This will return the number of days between a column named "B" and today's date.

If you're interested on creating other formula for calculated fields you can check them out in more detail [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Comment: So would it be possible to calculate a different date for each department that looks at the most recent date listed for a particular department and calculates based on that?

For Instance I may have
1-south    4/22/13
2-south    4/15/13
1-South    4/21/13

If today is the 25th, I would want both the 1-south entries to have a difference of 3 days, since the most recent entry was the 22nd.  2-south would have 10 days

Comment: I got confused. Can you explain in more detail what you need using column names as example so that it will be easier to understand? Have you tried the solution above or do you need something else?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for the answer to this:
Using the =DATEDIF([B], [Today], "d") formula above in a calculated column will give you the difference in days between the two dates.
If you need to further filter only the row with the latest occurrence, you need to configure a view.
Grouping by [A], sorting by [C], then use SP Designer to limit the group count to 1, or use xslt to only show the first of each group.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the "today" function; which SharePoint won't allow you to use, you must create a column for today's date.  This is done by simply adding a date column--which you can keep hidden.  Once you've created a date column you can use the formula =DATEDIF([Start Date],[However you labeled your date column],"d")